# R plotly: Adjust absolute marker size on 3D scatterplot

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am creating a 3D scatterplot using plotly in R and I would like to reduce the marker size of all points.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(iris,x=~Petal.Width,y=~Sepal.Width,z=~Petal.Length) %>% 
add_markers(color=~Species)
```

[image: default]

I tried to set the `sizes` argument, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

```
plot_ly(iris,x=~Petal.Width,y=~Sepal.Width,z=~Petal.Length) %>%
  add_markers(color=~Species,sizes=0.02)
```

Also tried another argument `sizeref`. Still, nothing happens.

```
plot_ly(iris,x=~Petal.Width,y=~Sepal.Width,z=~Petal.Length) %>%
  add_markers(color=~Species,marker=list(sizeref=0.02))
```

Any other solution to decrease the marker size of all points? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, the argument is `size`, and marker should go into `plot_ly()` instead of `add_markers()`.

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(iris,x=~Petal.Width,y=~Sepal.Width,z=~Petal.Length,
        marker = list(size = 20)) %>% 
   add_markers(color=~Species)
```

[image]